# Forecasting using fable and future, time & memory issues

Tags: r, time-series, future, forecasting, fable-r

I'm using fable and future to try to forecast in parallel, unfortunately it seems that for each iteration in the for loop, the `model()` step takes more time and consumes more memory.
What I am trying to do is step forward one week at a time and forecast a few weeks at each step using possibly multiple models at once.

The size of the data I am passing to the `model()` function is less than 1% larger each step but the time it takes to compute keeps growing exponentially. Below is a simplified example, in my case I do some computations on the values up to that point and pass it to model which makes this increase in compute time at each `model()` call only increase.

I did some investigation and the time increase seems to be coming from [this line](https://github.com/tidyverts/fabletools/blob/3370168ffe948860e8e885219931bd9f81c6ed0b/R/model.R#L116) in `fabletools`. I ran the debug option in the `future` package and the relevant code that is increasing in compute time there is [this](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future/blob/d3a3e55cfdfd1bc4c47df3790923ad15c8c0bed1/R/ClusterFuture-class.R#L194).

I believe that more data than is needed is being passed to each cluster node for each subsequent iteration of the loop. Is there a way that this can be avoided and ensure that only `cur_training_data` is passed down the stack?

Alternatively, maybe my whole strategy for doing this is off, I saw tsibble_stretch that could be a way to do this but I fear that replicating the training data for each time step would increase the footprint by a lot, this is why I went with the loop and filter. Is there a better way to do this in general?

Thanks very much for reading.

```
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(dtplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tsibbledata)
library(fable)
#> Loading required package: fabletools
library(tsibble)
library(logger)
library(future)
library(tidyquant)
#> Loading required package: lubridate
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:tsibble':
#> 
#>     interval
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union
#> Loading required package: PerformanceAnalytics
#> Loading required package: xts
#> Loading required package: zoo
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'zoo'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:tsibble':
#> 
#>     index
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     as.Date, as.Date.numeric
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'xts'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     first, last
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'PerformanceAnalytics'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:graphics':
#> 
#>     legend
#> Loading required package: quantmod
#> Loading required package: TTR
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'quantmod':
#>   method            from
#>   as.zoo.data.frame zoo
#> Version 0.4-0 included new data defaults. See ?getSymbols.
#> == Need to Learn tidyquant? =======================================================================================================================
#> Business Science offers a 1-hour course - Learning Lab #9: Performance Analysis & Portfolio Optimization with tidyquant!
#> </> Learn more at: https://university.business-science.io/p/learning-labs-pro </>
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'tidyquant'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:fable':
#> 
#>     VAR
library(tictoc)

# Set up some variables
my_vars <- NULL
# Value variable
my_vars$unit_column_name <- "adjusted"
# Whether to run in parallel or not
my_vars$run_parallel <- TRUE
# Number of cycles to forecast for
my_vars$num_cycles_to_forecast <- 9
# Weeks to predict for in each cycle
my_vars$weeks_to_predict <- 13
# Number of stock symbols
my_vars$num_stock_symbols <- 200

# Get stock data
stocks <- tq_index("SP500")
#> Getting holdings for SP500
symbols <- stocks %>% pull(symbol)

# Get stock price data
stock_prices  <- tq_get(symbols[1:my_vars$num_stock_symbols], 
                        get = "stock.prices", 
                        from = "2015-01-01")
#> Warning: Problem with `mutate()` input `data..`.
#> i x = 'BRK.B', get = 'stock.prices': Error in getSymbols.yahoo(Symbols = "BRK.B", env = <environment>, verbose = FALSE, : Unable to import "BRK.B".
#> BRK.B download failed after two attempts. Error message:
#> HTTP error 404.
#>  Removing BRK.B.
#> i Input `data..` is `purrr::map(...)`.
#> Warning: x = 'BRK.B', get = 'stock.prices': Error in getSymbols.yahoo(Symbols = "BRK.B", env = <environment>, verbose = FALSE, : Unable to import "BRK.B".
#> BRK.B download failed after two attempts. Error message:
#> HTTP error 404.
#>  Removing BRK.B.

# Convert to tsibble
stock_prices_tsibble <- stock_prices %>%
  as_tsibble(key = c(symbol),
             index = date)

# Prepare the training data, just need weekly data
weekly_stocks_tsibble <- stock_prices_tsibble %>%
  setNames(tolower(names(.))) %>%
  rename(forecast_week = date) %>%
  select(symbol, forecast_week, adjusted) %>%
  mutate(weekday = lubridate::wday(forecast_week)) %>%
  filter(weekday == 6) %>%
  select(-weekday) %>%
  as_tsibble(key = c(symbol),
             index = forecast_week) %>%
  fill_gaps(!!as.name({{my_vars$unit_column_name}}) := 0)

# Get the cycles we want to forecast for
my_vars$cycles_to_forecast <- weekly_stocks_tsibble %>% 
  slice_tail(n = my_vars$num_cycles_to_forecast) %>% 
  pull(forecast_week)


run_my_models <- function(cycles_to_forecast, actuals_column_name, weeks_to_predict, run_parallel, actuals_tsibble, ...) {
  
  # 
  if (run_parallel == TRUE) {
    plan(multiprocess)
  }
  
  # Tibble to hold results
  log_info("Creating holder tibble")
  holder_data_frame <- tibble()
  
  # Fit through cycles
  for (i in 1:length(cycles_to_forecast)) {
    # i <- 1
    
    cur_cycle <- cycles_to_forecast[i]
    
    log_info("Running for cycle {i}/{length(cycles_to_forecast)}: {cur_cycle}")
    
    # Prepare current cycles training data
    cur_training_data <- actuals_tsibble %>%
      filter(forecast_week < cur_cycle)
    
    # Check that there are rows in the training data
    if(nrow(cur_training_data) <= 0) {
      warn("No rows in current cycle training data")
      next()
    }
    
    log_info("Training data: {min(cur_training_data$forecast_week)} - {max(cur_training_data$forecast_week)}")
    tic()
    # Fit models
    cur_fit <- cur_training_data %>%
      model(...)
    
    log_info("Models fitted")
    toc()
    
    # Predict
    predictions <- cur_fit %>% 
      forecast(h = my_vars$weeks_to_predict, 
               point_forecast = list(forecasted_units = mean))
    
    log_info("Predictions generated")
    
    # Colect useful prediction information
    cur_fit_formatted <- cur_fit %>%
      as_tibble() %>%
      # mutate_if(~!is.character(.), print) %>%
      pivot_longer(cols = -c(symbol),
                   names_to = "method",
                   values_to = "method_specifics") %>%
      lazy_dt()
    
    collected_predictions <- predictions %>%
      as_tibble() %>%
      lazy_dt() %>%
      rename(method = .model) %>%
      left_join(cur_fit_formatted, by = c("symbol", "method")) %>%
      mutate(forecast_cycle = cur_cycle) %>%
      select(symbol, forecast_cycle, forecast_week, forecasted_units, method, method_specifics)
    
    log_info("Predictions colected")
    
    holder_data_frame <- holder_data_frame %>%
      bind_rows(as_tibble(collected_predictions))
    
  }
  
  return(holder_data_frame)
}

model_predictions <- run_my_models(cycles_to_forecast = my_vars$cycles_to_forecast,
                                   actuals_column_name = my_vars$unit_column_name,
                                   weeks_to_predict = my_vars$weeks_to_predict,
                                   run_parallel = my_vars$run_parallel,
                                   actuals_tsibble = weekly_stocks_tsibble,
                                   # Model definitions
                                   arima = ARIMA(!!as.name(my_vars$unit_column_name)))
#> INFO [2020-09-03 08:25:35] Creating holder tibble
#> INFO [2020-09-03 08:25:35] Running for cycle 1/9: 2020-07-03
#> INFO [2020-09-03 08:25:35] Training data: 2015-01-02 - 2020-06-26
#> INFO [2020-09-03 08:26:08] Models fitted
#> 33.27 sec elapsed
#> INFO [2020-09-03 08:26:10] Predictions generated
#> INFO [2020-09-03 08:26:10] Predictions colected
#> INFO [2020-09-03 08:26:11] Running for cycle 2/9: 2020-07-10
#> INFO [2020-09-03 08:26:11] Training data: 2015-01-02 - 2020-07-03
#> INFO [2020-09-03 08:26:42] Models fitted
#> 30.15 sec elapsed
#> INFO [2020-09-03 08:26:44] Predictions generated
#> INFO [2020-09-03 08:26:44] Predictions colected
#> INFO [2020-09-03 08:26:44] Running for cycle 3/9: 2020-07-17
#> INFO [2020-09-03 08:26:44] Training data: 2015-01-02 - 2020-07-10
#> INFO [2020-09-03 08:27:35] Models fitted
#> 50.63 sec elapsed
#> INFO [2020-09-03 08:27:37] Predictions generated
#> INFO [2020-09-03 08:27:37] Predictions colected
#> INFO [2020-09-03 08:27:38] Running for cycle 4/9: 2020-07-24
#> INFO [2020-09-03 08:27:38] Training data: 2015-01-02 - 2020-07-17
#> INFO [2020-09-03 08:28:43] Models fitted
#> 64.41 sec elapsed
#> INFO [2020-09-03 08:28:45] Predictions generated
#> INFO [2020-09-03 08:28:45] Predictions colected
#> INFO [2020-09-03 08:28:45] Running for cycle 5/9: 2020-07-31
#> INFO [2020-09-03 08:28:45] Training data: 2015-01-02 - 2020-07-24
#> INFO [2020-09-03 08:30:06] Models fitted
#> 81.08 sec elapsed
#> INFO [2020-09-03 08:30:09] Predictions generated
#> INFO [2020-09-03 08:30:09] Predictions colected
#> INFO [2020-09-03 08:30:09] Running for cycle 6/9: 2020-08-07
#> INFO [2020-09-03 08:30:09] Training data: 2015-01-02 - 2020-07-31
#> INFO [2020-09-03 08:31:55] Models fitted
#> 105.32 sec elapsed
#> INFO [2020-09-03 08:31:57] Predictions generated
#> INFO [2020-09-03 08:31:57] Predictions colected
#> INFO [2020-09-03 08:31:57] Running for cycle 7/9: 2020-08-14
#> INFO [2020-09-03 08:31:57] Training data: 2015-01-02 - 2020-08-07
#> INFO [2020-09-03 08:34:00] Models fitted
#> 123.16 sec elapsed
#> INFO [2020-09-03 08:34:02] Predictions generated
#> INFO [2020-09-03 08:34:02] Predictions colected
#> INFO [2020-09-03 08:34:02] Running for cycle 8/9: 2020-08-21
#> INFO [2020-09-03 08:34:02] Training data: 2015-01-02 - 2020-08-14
#> INFO [2020-09-03 08:36:27] Models fitted
#> 144.39 sec elapsed
#> INFO [2020-09-03 08:36:29] Predictions generated
#> INFO [2020-09-03 08:36:29] Predictions colected
#> INFO [2020-09-03 08:36:29] Running for cycle 9/9: 2020-08-28
#> INFO [2020-09-03 08:36:29] Training data: 2015-01-02 - 2020-08-21
#> INFO [2020-09-03 08:39:06] Models fitted
#> 156.76 sec elapsed
#> INFO [2020-09-03 08:39:08] Predictions generated
#> INFO [2020-09-03 08:39:08] Predictions colected
```

`sessionInfo()`

```
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows Server x64 (build 14393)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Ireland.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Ireland.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Ireland.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                    
[5] LC_TIME=English_Ireland.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] ps_1.3.4        digest_0.6.25   crayon_1.3.4    R6_2.4.1        lifecycle_0.2.0 reprex_0.3.0    magrittr_1.5    evaluate_0.14  
 [9] pillar_1.4.4    rlang_0.4.7     rstudioapi_0.11 fs_1.5.0        callr_3.4.3     whisker_0.4     vctrs_0.3.3     ellipsis_0.3.1 
[17] rmarkdown_2.3   tools_4.0.2     processx_3.4.3  xfun_0.16       compiler_4.0.2  pkgconfig_2.0.3 clipr_0.7.0     htmltools_0.5.0
[25] knitr_1.29      tibble_3.0.3
```